# Transfer Minecraft Windows 10 saves from computer to computer?

Tags: windows-10, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got a new laptop, would like to keep playing MC. I've already managed to copy the save file over but can't open it in-game because none of the files are in the proper format.

What file should I be on the lookout for?

Answer (score 1):

An Exported Minecraft world for Minecraft Windows 10 Edition will save with the .mcworld File extension. this file is not in the folder where MCWin10 saves the games but rather is attained by Exporting the world using the ingame options.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are playing Minecraft Windows 10 edition, you have to export and it will be opened only by Minecraft for Windows 10 because it is an `.mcworld` file. If you are playing Minecraft Java edition, you have to copy from `saves` folder and paste it in your new `saves` folder on your new laptop.